# How to deserialize with a binaryformatter in a background thread in .NET 4?

Tags: wpf, serialization, task-parallel-library, background-process

I am trying to load files in a background thread while displaying a progressbar in the UI. It seems that the `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` function as well as the updates to the `ProgressBar` need to be run on a STA thread.  I am using the TPL library to pass the T`askScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` into the loading task, but this seems to schedule the `progressbar` updates and the file loading onto the *same* thread, so that they occur serially instead of in parallel.

I have tried passing `TaskScheduler.Default` into the `LoadModelTask` instead, but this gives an STA error on the `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` call.

Is there another way to load WPF objects in the background that doesn't require me to freeze the UI thread?

My code:

```
        private void openFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.DefaultExt = FILE_EXTENSION;
            dialog.Filter = "MFlow Documents|*.mpex;*.mpxc;*.mpoc";

            Nullable<bool> result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {                
                string filename = dialog.FileName;

                var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
                CancellationTokenSource source=new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = source.Token;

                feedbackWindow = new FeedbackWindow();
                feedbackWindow.ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;
                feedbackWindow.ProgressLabel.Content = "Opening " + filename;
                feedbackWindow.Show();

                Task<Model> loadModelTask=
                    Task.Factory.StartNew<Model>(() => LoadModel(filename),
                    token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                loadModelTask.ContinueWith(task => AfterLoadModel(task), scheduler);

            }
        }

        private static Model LoadModel(string filename)
        {
            Model returnModel;
            string extension = filename.Split('.')[filename.Split('.').Length - 1];

            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
                using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var test = formatter.Deserialize(gZipStream);
                    returnModel = (Model)formatter.Deserialize(gZipStream);

                    gZipStream.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            return returnModel;
        }

        private void AfterLoadModel(Task<Model> task)
        {
            try
            {
                task.Wait();
                switch (task.Status)
                {
                    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                        ModelResult = task.Result;
                        feedbackWindow.Close();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                // For demonstration purposes, show the OCE message. 
                foreach (Exception v in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("msg: " + v.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

*Is there another way to load WPF objects in the background that doesn't require me to freeze the UI thread?*

Absolutely, positively not.

WPF UI elements have *thread affinity*, which means that they can only be touched using the thread within which they were instantiated.  Since parent UIElements call methods in their child UIElements, the same thread that is responsible for the construction of the root element within your visual tree must be the same thread that constructs *all* UIElements within the visual tree.

For more information, please [read this article on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441.aspx#System_Threading_DispatcherObject)

**If you're serializing/deserializing UIElements** you're already doing it wrong.  You should describe your data in terms of Models (POCO classes) and ViewModels (essentially Models but with change notification) that are deserialized, bound to your UI, and displayed via UIElements described within DataTemplates.  This is commonly referred to as the MVVM pattern, and allows you to act on your data asynchronously without worrying (much) about threading in your UI (when done correctly).

**If you're just trying to update your UI during a long-running operation** its better to have a property bound to your UI which describes how far along your operation is and either update your UI using a DispatcherTimer (reading the current state of the property) or use an asynchronous binding to automatically update the UI(I believe INPC property bindings automatically handle marshaling calls to the UI thread for you).

And, last note, if an operation takes under two seconds, don't slow it down just to show a progress bar.  Your users will thank you.

Comment: Bindings don't marshal anything to the UI thread.  Changing a property and raising the INPC event in a non-UI thread is just as bad as touching the UIElement from that thread.

Comment: @zmb wanna blow your mind?  Spin up a sample and try it yourself.  Not at my office or I'd tell you he specs.

Comment: Ah - looks like you're correct (as of .NET 3.5).  I think what I said is still true for Silverlight, .NET prior to 3.5 and for collections and `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: @zmb but... Did it blow your mind?  Did mine.  Also made my code more compact.

Comment: @Will, I may have given the wrong message with the phrase 
"WPF Object".  I am not instantiating UI elements, but am loading a viewmodel and its associated model.  Neither of these objects has any direct UI objects associated with it.

Comment: @Sandy: Then re-read the bolded second paragraph.  That's what you need to do.  [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332814/update-progressbar-from-a-backgroundworker-in-wpf) is essentially what you have to do--use the UI dispatcher to run a function which will update your UI.